# how to connect python code in venv with s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

need some help to connect my python code, which runs in a virtual environment (AWS ec2) with S3 on AWS.

i already connect the instance via IAM - that works. it is also possible to run the code in my pycharm environment. but if i run the code on my ec2 the error is: NO module name boto3! But i install the module with requirements.text. i run the code i a shell

awscli==1.18.222

fsspec==0.8.5

s3fs==0.5.2

boto3==1.16.51

boto3-stubs==1.16.59.0

botocore==1.17.44

s3ts==0.1.0

think that's more than necessary.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/code/namexy

git pull
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 venv
(
 source venv/bin/activate
 pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 python main.py
)

git add *
git commit -m "AWS ec2: data_main"
git push origin main
```

Comment: Are you sure that `pip3` is running after the `source` statement? The `source` command might be running another shell environment. I suggest putting in some debugging after the `source` command to make sure it is getting there.

Comment: @Alex - `s3fs` at the most must be on release `0.5.1`. I think it must be failing due at `s3fs` install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem "may" was, that installed a package which removed boto3 package (botocore). now my code looks like this and runs!

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/code/namexy
git pull

rm -rf venv
mkdir venv

pip3 install --user virtualenv

virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/python3
source venv/python3/bin/activate

pip3 install -r requirements.txt
pip3 freeze

python3 main.py 

deactivate

git add *
git commit -m "AWS ec2: "main"
git push origin main
```